# How to create a Django FloatField with maximum and minimum limits?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm storing some floating-point data in my Django models, and only a certain range of values are meaningful. Therefore, I'd like to impose these limits at both the model and SQL constraint level.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Foo(Model):
   myfloat = FloatField(min=0.0, max=1.0)
```

I want to do this at the model level, not the form level. In fact, I might like the form level to have a different range; e.g., use percentages [0,100] at the form level but translate to [0,1] in the model.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 173):

The answers so far describe how to make forms validate.  You can also put validators in the model.  Use [MinValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) and [MaxValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator).

For example:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

...
weight = models.FloatField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)],
)
```

**EDIT**:

However, that does not add a SQL constraint.

You can add SQL constraints as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/) as `CheckConstraint`s in `Meta.constraints`.

Combined example:

```py
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q

class Foo(Model):
    myfloat = FloatField(min=0.0, max=1.0,
        # for checking in forms
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)],)

    class Meta:
        constraints = (
            # for checking in the DB
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(myfloat__gte=0.0) & Q(myfloat__lte=1.0),
                name='foo_myfloat_range'),
            )
```

Comment: However these validators don't work at the model level, at least not automatically. You can save a model with `weight` exceeding these limits alright. It's just that form validation will automatically pick up these validators.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Over a year later, but I added `CheckConstraint` for the DB constraint.

Answer (score 22):

If you need constraint on form level you can pass `min_value` and `max_value` to [form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield):

```
myfloat = forms.FloatField(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)
```

But if you need to move it up to model level you have to extend base `models.FloatField` class

```
class MinMaxFloat(models.FloatField):
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        super(MinMaxFloat, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value' : self.max_value}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(MinMaxFloat, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Then you can use it in models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    myfloat = MinMaxFloat(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)
```

Comment: OK. And then extending the MinMaxFloat to actually validate against those values, and create database constraints, would be up to me?

Comment: It creates constraint on django model level, i.e. you can insert record manually like `Foo(myfloat=-1.0).save()`, but you will get ValidationError when try to send `ModelForm` based on your `Foo` model

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite some time and the community voted answer is good enough, based on Django built-ins, but here is another approach, problem specific, following the [Django Project's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/).

#### Create a custom validator

```
# app/models.py or create another file for custom validators, i.e. app/custom_validators.py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _  # use if you support internationalization

def validate_interval(value):
    if value < 0.0 or value > 1.0:
        raise ValidationError(_('%(value)s must be in the range [0.0, 1.0]'), params={'value': value},)
```

#### Use your validator in your models

```
# app/models.py

class Foo(models.Model):
    myfloat = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_interval])
```

You can even make the validator parametric to be more generic.

### EDIT - IMPORTANT

Bare in mind that any validator is invoked during the form's `clean()` method.

I.E. if you try to directly create an object without using a form, your validator will **NOT** be invoked.

There are those who don't recommend it but if you want to invoke validators while creating an object override the save method.

```
# app/models.py

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _  # use if you support internationalization


class Foo(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()  # or clean
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate_interval(value):
        if value < 0.0 or value > 1.0:
            raise ValidationError(_('%(value)s must be in the range [0.0, 1.0]'), params={'value': value},)

    myfloat = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_interval])
```

Comment: i put a logger inside the validation function, and it doesn't run

Comment: Please read carefully the provided resources.
If you read in the link provided in my original answer it is clarified that the validator is called in the `ModelForm's clean()` method.

Quoting from the link : `Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model`.

I assume that you try to directly create an object, i.e. using `save()` method and thus the validator is never to be called.
If you create an object using a form the validator will be utilized. Otherwise you can override the `save()` method.

Comment: I understand why someone downvoted (as the question is quite specific), but really this answer is a helpful addition, and gives perspective on why you might want to use different approaches to validation