# Why does cloning this subclass of FloatField (with added validators) throw an exception?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Python and Django.

I want my model to have range-validated floats. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539026/how-to-create-a-django-floatfield-with-maximum-and-minimum-limits) I wrote this:

```
class FloatRangeField (FloatField):
    """A FloatField constrained to a given range."""

    def __init__ (self, minimum, maximum, **kwargs):

        minmax = [MinValueValidator (minimum), MaxValueValidator (maximum)]

        print ("\n\t\tFloatRangeField({},{})".format(minimum,maximum)) # (A)
        FloatField.__init__ (self, validators = minmax, **kwargs)
        print ("\t\tFINISHED\n")
```

This was causing errors in `python3 manage.py migrate`, I narrowed it down to a `clone()` call. Demonstration:

```
print ("HERE 1")
tmp1 = FloatRangeField (10, 20)
print ("HERE 2")
tmp2 = FloatRangeField (10, 20)
print ("HERE 3")
tmp3 = tmp1.clone ()      # (B)
print ("HERE 4")
```

It throws an exception from line `# (B)`. Oddly, when this happens, the trace at line `# (A)` is *not* printed. Here is the output:

```
HERE 1

                FloatRangeField(10,20)
                FINISHED

HERE 2

                FloatRangeField(10,20)
                FINISHED

HERE 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

[...snip...]

    tmp3 = tmp1.clone ()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 470, in clone
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'minimum' and 'maximum'
```

As well as the weirdness of nothing being printed at `# (A)`, this is *not* the same as the error which I saw during `migrate`. If I take out the `tmp1=...` stuff and run `migrate`, the traceback looks like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 411, in from_model
    fields.append((name, field.clone()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 470, in clone
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)

[...snip...]

    FloatField.__init__ (self, validators = minmax, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'validators'
```

Why is this breaking and how should I implement `FloatRangeField` so as to encapsulate the having of min/max validators?

Comment: Well the error is rather clear: it is unable to clone the field, since there are two arguments missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like is written in the [documentation on custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction):

> If you add a new keyword argument, you need to write code to put its value into `kwargs` yourself (...)

So you should add a deconstructor as well. This is necessary, for example to represent this field in a migration file:

```
class FloatRangeField (FloatField):
    """A FloatField constrained to a given range."""

    def __init__ (self, minimum, maximum, **kwargs):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        minmax = [MinValueValidator (minimum), MaxValueValidator (maximum)]
        FloatField.__init__ (self, validators = minmax, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        result = __, __, __, kwargs = super(FloatRangeField, self).deconstruct()
        kwargs['minimum'] = self.minimum
        kwargs['minimum'] = self.maximum
        del kwargs['validators']
        return result
```

Note that you better do not use `validators = minmax` as parameter, since that will mean that if a user would use the `validator` parameters for your `FloatRangeField` constructor, there will be a parameter clash.

For example it is possible to *append* our `minmax` validators to the validators that already exist, and then later pop these back from the validator when we want to deconstruct it:

```
class FloatRangeField (FloatField):
    """A FloatField constrained to a given range."""

    def __init__ (self, minimum, maximum, **kwargs):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        old_validators = kwargs.get('validators', [])
        minmax = [MinValueValidator (minimum), MaxValueValidator (maximum)]
        minmax += old_validators
        kwargs['validators'] = minmax
        FloatField.__init__ (self, **kwargs)
    

    def deconstruct(self):
        result = __, __, __, kwargs = super(FloatRangeField, self).deconstruct()
        kwargs['minimum'] = self.minimum
        kwargs['minimum'] = self.maximum
        kwargs['validators'] = kwargs['validators'][2:]
        return result
```

So here we in the `deconstruct(..)` function, we remove the first two validators (that we added in the `__init__(..)` function).