# FloatField __init__ got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_value'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951852/why-does-cloning-this-subclass-of-floatfield-with-added-validators-throw-an-ex/50951987#50951987) and solved my problem as originally stated. The following code works:

```
class FloatRangeField (FloatField):
    """A FloatField constrained to a given range."""

    def __init__ (self, minimum, maximum, **kwargs):

        minmax = [MinValueValidator (minimum), MaxValueValidator (maximum)]

        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

        kwargs ['validators'] = minmax

        FloatField.__init__ (self, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct (self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super () .deconstruct ()

        kwargs ['minimum'] = self.minimum
        kwargs ['maximum'] = self.maximum

        del kwargs ['validators']

        return name, path, args, kwargs



class AffinityField (FloatRangeField):
    """An affinity is a float from -1 (hate) to +1 (love)."""

    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        FloatRangeField.__init__ (self, -1.0, 1.0, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct (self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super () .deconstruct ()

        del kwargs ['minimum']
        del kwargs ['maximum']

        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

However, I don't believe this is quite complete. I am new to Django, but my understanding is that adding validators constrains the data that the model is willing to save, but separately from this, as [this answer indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539731/458742), there is validation at the form level.

> If you need constraint on form level you can pass min_value and max_value to form field:
>
> ```
> myfloat = forms.FloatField(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)
> ```

I don't have any visible forms yet (just starting to learn!) so I don't know if it is necessary to do this separately, but from the sounds of it I *do* have to pass `min_value` and `max_value` as well as the validator objects. Here is my attempt:

```
class FloatRangeField (FloatField):
    """A FloatField constrained to a given range."""

    def __init__ (self, minimum, maximum, **kwargs):

        minmax = [MinValueValidator (minimum), MaxValueValidator (maximum)]

        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

        # Validators for the model
        kwargs ['validators'] = minmax

        # Arguments for the form validation
        kwargs ['min_value']  = minimum
        kwargs ['max_value']  = maximum

        FloatField.__init__ (self, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct (self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super () .deconstruct ()

        kwargs ['minimum'] = self.minimum
        kwargs ['maximum'] = self.maximum

        del kwargs ['validators']
        del kwargs ['min_value']
        del kwargs ['max_value']

        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

This throws an exception:

```
    FloatField.__init__ (self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_value'
```

But [according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield), the `min_value` argument *is* expected, so I don't know what this error really means.

I thought I understood the principle of field deconstructors (delete from `kwargs` those things which you don't need as inputs when you define them in the child class's `__init__`) but perhaps not.

What's wrong with how I'm using `min_value` and `max_value`?

Comment: The parameters are `minum` and `maximum`, not `min_value` and `max_value`.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield): "Takes two optional arguments for validation, max_value and min_value. These control the range of values permitted in the field."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you mixed [form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/) and [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField). Link you provided in your question described form's `FloatField`.

But model's [`FloatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField) which you are trying to customize doesn't have `min_value` and `max_value` arguments by default.