# Limit max and min values in django field model

Tags: django

Let's say I have a model

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    rating = models.FloatField()
```

The rating is not defined by any user but rather calculated by a script, so it will change over and over as the time goes. And I also want it to never drop below 0 and go above 100 (so if it becomes less than 0 then it's 0 and if it goes above 100 then it's 100).

Is it possible to set this limitation on model level or do I need to adjust every script that works with this model to take this into account?

Comment: How do the scripts interact with that model, through a form/serializer?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to set this limitation on model level or do I need to adjust every script that works with this model to take this into account?

**Yes**, you can restrict the field both when validating with forms and at the database side with validators and constraints:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db.models import Q


class Thing(models.Model):
    rating = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)]
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(rating__range=(0, 100)), name='rating_in_range'
            )
        ]
```

But this will not *truncate* the value, it will just reject it at the database side (through the constraints), and in forms and serializers (through the validators).

We can generate the truncate logic by renaming the field `_rating` for example, and let a property handle the rating logic:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db.models import Q


class Thing(models.Model):
    _rating = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)],
        db_column='rating',
    )

    @property
    def rating(self):
        return self._rating

    @rating.setter
    def rating(self, value):
        self._rating = max(0, min(value, 100))

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(_rating__range=(0, 100)), name='rating_in_range'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! I should've remembered about property myself.

Answer (score 0):

Like below.

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

...
weight = models.FloatField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)],
)
```

Look at this answer for more info.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776059/13861187)